# Deploy to Sepolia Infura Foundry: Solidity Scripting

Tags: contract-deployment, testnets, infura, foundry, forge

I'm trying to deploy my contract with Foundry Solidity Scripting to Infura on the Seoplia test net. But Im getting this weird issue that appears to be related to the Infura API Key (formerly Project ID). I copied the seoplia URL from the Insura dashboard into my .env

```
❯ forge script script/ICO.s.sol:MyScript --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --broadcast --verify -vvvv                                                     ─╯
Error: 
(code: -32002, message: rejected due to project ID settings, data: None)
```

## Update

From this starter repo: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/foundry-starter-kit

`forge script script/ICO.s.sol:MyScript --rpc-url ${SEPOLIA_RPC_URL}  --private-key ${PRIVATE_KEY} --broadcast --verify --etherscan-api-key ${ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}  -vvvv`

and I'm getting a slightly different output:

```
[⠒] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
2023-03-09T08:51:48.418184Z ERROR sharedbackend: Failed to send/recv `basic` err=GetAccount(0x1804c8ab1f12e6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38, 
(code: -32002, message: rejected due to project ID settings, data: None)) address=0x1804c8ab1f12e6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
Error: 
Failed to get account for 0x1804c8ab1f12e6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38: 0x1804c8ab1f12e6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
```

`script/ICO.s.sol`

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "forge-std/Script.sol";
import "../src/contracts/ICO.sol";

contract MyScript is Script {
    function run() external {
        uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");

        vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);

        address treasury = address(this);
        address[] memory approvedSigners = new address[](0);

        approvedSigners[0] = address(this);

        ICO ico = new ICO(treasury, approvedSigners);

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was able to get it to work with `forge create` but it's a terribly long command and I'd prefer to get it working with Solidity scripting:

`forge create src/contracts/ICO.sol:ICO --verify --etherscan-api-key $ETHERSCAN_API_KEY  --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL  --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY  --constructor-args "0xA247e0BCEb1a503a290e39BE7310C7B2C253fd80" "[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the --verify argument, I think when deploy with scripting you need to run `forge verify`in a separate command.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried this and I get the same error: `forge script script/ICO.s.sol:MyScript --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --broadcast  -vvvv`

Also I got the command from the foundry book: https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/solidity-scripting